# Python / Numba create histogram from ranges

Tags: python, histogram, cython, numba

I want to create a histogram (1d) from given ranges and I want it to be fast. This is why also cython and numba can be taken into consideration.

Given are two boundaries, weights and a stepsize.

For example:

```
boundaries1 = np.array([511.4, 517.5, 517.2, 520.1, 519.8])
boundaries2 = np.array([517.3, 517.1, 517.8, 518.2, 515.0])
weights = np.array([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1])
stepsize = 0.1
```

Note, that the boundaries are not sorted by their value, meaning that e.g. a boundary1 could be greater or lower as the corresponding boundary2.

The result for this example should return a histogram with the given stepsize, the minimum value and the maximum value.

```
histogram = np.array([0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2,
       0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2,
       0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2,
       1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2,
       1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.6, 2.2, 2.2, 2. , 2. , 1.6, 1.6, 1.6,
       1. , 1. , 1. , 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8,
       1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8])
minimum = 511.4
maximum =  520.1
```

Are there creative ideas on how to implement this to run as fast as possible?

This is my current approach:

```
@njit(cache=True)
def create_histogram(boundaries1, boundaries2, weights, stepsize):
    minimum = np.minimum(np.min(boundaries1),np.min(boundaries2))
    maximum = np.maximum(np.max(boundaries1),np.max(boundaries2))

    num_bins = int(np.round((maximum-minimum+stepsize)/stepsize))
    hist = np.zeros(num_bins, dtype=np.float64)
        
    lower = np.round((np.minimum(boundaries1, boundaries2)-minimum)/stepsize).astype(np.int32)
    upper = np.round((np.maximum(boundaries1, boundaries2)-minimum)/stepsize).astype(np.int32)
    
    for i in range(lower.shape[0]):
        hist[lower[i]:upper[i]+1] += weights[i]
    
    return hist, minimum, maximum
```

Comment: So, where the regions overlap, the result is the sum?

Comment: Yes, thats correct

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following solution against your current approach with the same data. It seems to have reduced the time taken to almost half.

Test Data:

```
boundaries1 = np.array([511.4, 517.5, 517.2, 520.1, 519.8])
boundaries2 = np.array([517.3, 517.1, 517.8, 518.2, 515.0])
weights = np.array([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1])
stepsize = 0.1
```

#### A faster approach

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, prange
import time

@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True, cache=True)
def create_histogram_numba(boundaries1, boundaries2, weights, stepsize):
    min_boundary = min(min(boundaries1), min(boundaries2))
    max_boundary = max(max(boundaries1), max(boundaries2))
    
    num_bins = int((max_boundary - min_boundary) / stepsize) + 1
    hist = np.zeros(num_bins, dtype=np.float64)
    
    for i in prange(len(boundaries1)):
        start = int((min(boundaries1[i], boundaries2[i]) - min_boundary) / stepsize)
        end = int((max(boundaries1[i], boundaries2[i]) - min_boundary) / stepsize)
        for j in range(start, end):
            hist[j] += weights[i]
    
    return hist, min_boundary, max_boundary

start = time.time()
print("Faster approach")
hist = create_histogram_numba(boundaries1, boundaries2, weights, stepsize)
end = time.time()
print("Time taken(s): {}".format(end-start))
print("Historgam: ", hist[0], "\nMinimum: ", hist[1], "\nMaximum: ", hist[2])
```

Output:

```
Faster approach
Time taken(s): 1.2022387981414795
Historgam:  [0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2
 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.6 2.  2.  2.  1.6 1.6 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8
 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0. ] 
Minimum:  511.4 
Maximum:  520.1
```

###### Your current approach:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, prange
import time

@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True, cache=True)
def create_histogram(boundaries1, boundaries2, weights, stepsize):
    minimum = np.minimum(np.min(boundaries1),np.min(boundaries2))
    maximum = np.maximum(np.max(boundaries1),np.max(boundaries2))

    num_bins = int(np.round((maximum-minimum+stepsize)/stepsize))
    hist = np.zeros(num_bins, dtype=np.float64)
        
    lower = np.round((np.minimum(boundaries1, boundaries2)-minimum)/stepsize).astype(np.int32)
    upper = np.round((np.maximum(boundaries1, boundaries2)-minimum)/stepsize).astype(np.int32)
    
    for i in range(lower.shape[0]):
        hist[lower[i]:upper[i]+1] += weights[i]
    
    return hist, minimum, maximum

start = time.time()
print("your current appraoch")
hist = create_histogram(boundaries1, boundaries2, weights, stepsize)
end = time.time()
print("Time taken(s): {}".format(end-start))
print("Historgam: ", hist[0], "\nMinimum: ", hist[1], "\nMaximum: ", hist[2])
```

Output:

```
your current appraoch
Time taken(s): 2.93923277854919434
Historgam:  [0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2
 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.6 2.2 2.2 2.  2.  1.6 1.6 1.6 1.  1.  1.  1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8
 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 0.8 0.8 0.8] 
Minimum:  511.4 
Maximum:  520.1
```

Comment: Nice, this one utilizes the parallel abilities of numba. It is a nice way, but unfortunately does not fit my application as the whole function already runs in parallel processes.

Comment: yeah also, doing `np,min`, `np.max`, `np.round` just adds up to the time

Comment: Hm I just saw, that the results of your code and mine are not the same. For yours, the last few values are:  1.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0. ]
For mine it's:  1.8 1.8 1.8 0.8 0.8 0.8]

Actually I found in my tests, that the `round` is necessary, otherwise the `num_bins`, `lower`or `upper` values migth be wrong.

Comment: yeah, I just saw that, mine is generating zero for the last value whereas yours was 0,8. Anyway, don't use `np.min`, `np.max`. and use `round` instead of `np.round` if possible

Answer (score 0):

I made some adjustments to the code of @Musabbir Arrafi to fit my application, these are:

- no use of prange
- use `round`, to make sure to get the number of bins and the bin indices right

The new code is:

```
def create_histogram4(boundaries1, boundaries2, weights, stepsize):
minimum = min(min(boundaries1), min(boundaries2))
maximum = max(max(boundaries1), max(boundaries2))

# num_bins = int((maximum - minimum) / stepsize) + 1
num_bins = round((maximum-minimum)/stepsize) + 1

hist = np.zeros(num_bins, dtype=np.float64)
    
for i in range(len(boundaries1)):
    start = round((min(boundaries1[i], boundaries2[i]) - minimum) / stepsize)
    end = round((max(boundaries1[i], boundaries2[i]) - minimum) / stepsize)
    for j in range(start, end+1):
        hist[j] += weights[i]


return hist, minimum, maximum
```

This is around 3.7x faster then my previous code. Thank you Musabbir!